# Word and SharePoint managed metadata : problem using several tenants at once

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, term-store, multi-tenancy

I got a customer using SharePoint 2013 but they are going to migrate to SharePoint SSE.

We designed a new document architecture and a migration is planned in the next months. It will be performed project by project, that means people may have to connect sometimes to the old SharePoint and sometimes to the new SharePoint.

During test sessions, sometimes managed metadata properties were greyed out in Word, it seems Word sometimes connect to the bad term store. Cleaning the cache helps.

But, is there any solution to force Word to connect to the appropriate term store, all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to force Word to connect to a specific term store for managed metadata properties. However, cleaning the cache can help resolve the issue when Word connects to the wrong term store. It's important to ensure that only one Managed Metadata Service (MMS) term store is set as the default for the site collection to avoid this issue. If more than one site collection term store is marked as the default, the SharePoint Migration Tool can't determine which term store to migrate, which can break managed metadata columns that refer to the term store content.